# how can i print custom class Duplicate if i am adding that object in list?

Tags: java, list

How can i print the duplicate of custom class object if i am adding that object inside list.

```
class Bank{
int id;
String name;
public Bank(int id,String name){
 this.id=id;
 this.name=name;
  }
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.equals(obj);
} 
 @Override
 public String toString() {

return id+"\t"+name;
    }
    }

   public class Service {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   List<Bank> al=new ArrayList<Bank>();
   Bank a=new Bank(11,"employee");
   Bank b=new Bank(11,"employee");
   Bank c=new Bank(12,"Bank");
   Bank d=new Bank(12,"Bank");
   al.add(a);
   al.add(b);
   al.add(c);
   al.add(d);
   }}
```

Here four bank object i am adding inside list. But a,b pointing to same object and similarly c and d pointing to same object How can i pointing to duplicate from above List.

Comment: a and b, and likewise c and d do *not* point to the same object. The objects they point to may be *equal* if `equals` is implemented in a certain way, but `class Bank` doesn't show it.

Comment: equals method is also over-ride then also it is possible

Comment: Your implementation of `equals` is useless. When are two Bank objects "equal"? This is a question of the interpretation of the field values.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options to achieve this...

1st one is out of the box:

you need to use a Set, this collection doesnt allow duplicates, but you has no insertion order

2nd option.
you can write a method that is checking in the list is the element you are trying to insert is already there... list.contains(bank); where bank is the mthod to check...

in both cases is necessary to override the methods `hashcode` and `equals`(you already have this) in the class bank.

## Example:

```
static List<Bank> al;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    al = new ArrayList<Bank>();
    Bank a = new Bank(11, "employee");
    Bank b = new Bank(11, "employee");
    Bank c = new Bank(12, "Bank");
    Bank d = new Bank(12, "Bank");
    addIfNotinList(a);
    addIfNotinList(b);
    addIfNotinList(c);
    addIfNotinList(d);
    System.out.println(al);

}

private static void addIfNotinList(Bank bank) {
    if (!al.contains(bank)) {
        al.add(bank);
    }
}
```

---

and the Bank class

public class Bank {
    int id;
    String name;

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + id;
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Bank other = (Bank) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    return true;
}

public Bank(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Bank [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
}
```

}

Comment: if i am overriding equals and hashcode for Bank then index value will be change for Bank so i think this not correct way.

Comment: For the second option, hashCode isn't really necessary (although one is well advised to implemented it nevertheless).

Comment: If hascode return some value and equals method return true then index value will be 1 and equals return false then index value become -1

Comment: @Ankit Go and read some documentation about hashCode, equals and their use.

Comment: very deeply i read and practically implemented by me. But not able to getting accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Implement equals according to:

```
public boolean equals( Object obj ){
    if ( this == obj ) return true;
    if ( !(obj instanceof Bank) ) return false;
    Bank other = (Bank)obj;
    return this.id == other.id && this.name == other.name; 
}
```

Perhaps comparing the id alone would be sufficient to establish equality.

Now you can do:

```
List<Bank> al=new ArrayList<Bank>();
Bank a=new Bank(11,"employee");
al.add( a );
Bank b=new Bank(11,"employee");
if( al.contains( b ) ){
    // duplicate
} else {
    al.add( b );
}
```